# How to associate multiple component in one redux-form Field component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I have a scenario where there will be two fields of each item. One field is a checkbox and another is dropdown but the point is to get a pair of data from this and I am mapping this based on the item(they have category too). And the dropdown depends on checkbox(when unchecked the dropdown is disabled and value is reset to none or zero)

I tried

```
<Field name={ `${item.label}` } component={MyCheckBoxComponent}>
<Field name={ `${item.value}` } component={MyDropDownComponent}>
```

what happens is each of them have unique `name` and I cant do anything when I need to update the values depending on the checkbox selections.
I have tried putting the two inputs in one `Field` but I can't get it to work. Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Redux Fields (https://redux-form.com/6.0.4/docs/api/fields.md/)  not Redux Field.
You can create a separate component which wraps your check-box component and your drop-down component.

This is how you use it

```
<Fields 
  names={[ 
    checkboxFieldName,
    dropDownFieldName 
  ]}
  component={MyMultiFieldComponent}
  anotherCustomProp="Some other information"
/>
```

And the props that you get in your **MyMultiFieldComponent**

```
{
  checkboxFieldName: { input: { ... }, meta: { ... } },
  dropDownFieldName: { input: { ... }, meta: { ... } },
  anotherCustomProp: 'Some other information'
}
```

The input property has a onChange property (which is a method), you can call it to update the respective field value.

For example in onChange method of check-box

```
onChangeCheckbox (event) {
  const checked = event.target.checked;
  if (checked) {
    // write your code when checkbox is selected
  } else {
    const { checkboxFieldName, dropDownFieldName } = props;
    checkboxFieldName.input.onChange('Set it to something');
    dropDownFieldName.input.onChange('set to zero or none');
  }
}
```

This way you can update multiple field values at the same time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: took me a while to figure it out but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is what are you looking for - `formValues` decorator.

Just wrap your dropdown with this decorator and pass the name into it of your checkbox so you will have access inside of the `MyDropDownComponent`.

For example:

```
import { formValues } from 'redux-form';

<form ...>
    <Field name="myCheckBox" component={MyCheckBoxComponent}>
    <Field name="myDropdown" component={formValues('myCheckBox')(MyDropDownComponent)} />
</form>
```

So then `myCheckBox` value will be passed as a prop.

Performance note:

> This decorator causes the component to render() every time one of the selected values changes.

Use this sparingly.

See more here - https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formvalues.md/